# Routing conflicing with another, /articles/article_name_here and /articles/archives

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes has:

```
resources :articles
```

article_controller.rb has:

```
def show()
   @article = Article.find(:first, :conditions => {:title => params[:id]}) 
end

def archives()
end
```

Now the show() method respondes to the article_name, not the ID.

So the problem is, the url:

```
www.example.com/article/this-is-a-title
```

conflicts with:

```
www.example.com/article/archives
```

as it thinks the parameter 'archives' is a article title and maps to the show() action.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the resources definition make another route

```
match 'article/archives', :to => 'articles#archives'
```

Top routes take precedence over bottom routes.